# Unexplained increase in VMMS.exe memory usage in Hyper-V

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I've encountered a peculiar issue with Hyper-V that I hope someone can shed some light on. I noticed a significant increase in RAM usage attributed to the VMMS (Virtual Machine Management Service) process on my Hyper-V host.

The VMMS process consumes around 8.9GB of RAM (out of a total of 32GB), even when there are no virtual machines running.

This process swelled to this size within 30 seconds of restarting the service.

Here are some details about my environment:

- Windows 11 Enterprise 23H2 22631.2715 Experience Pack 1000.22677.1000.0
- Windows updated to 23H2 three weeks ago and is up to date with the latest updates.
- There have been no recent software installations or updates since updating to 23H2.
- No WSL/Docker/Windows Sandbox is running on the machine.
- Defender and Malwarebytes scans didn't reveal any issues.
- I've checked event logs, reviewed resource allocations, and examined running processes, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the cause.
- I've restarted the machine many times.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to identify and resolve this issue.

[image: vmms.exe]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you also provide a screenshot of the “Performance” tab? Thanks.